# Saving Many-To-Many Relationship with Entity Framework to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, devexpress

I have **BOM** and **Project** table which are many-to-many.

Following is my code for **BOM**

```
public class BOM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    [StringLength(OwnConstants.StringLengthShort)]
    public string BOMRevision { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    [Index("BOM Code", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(OwnConstants.StringLengthShort)]
    public string BOMCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    [StringLength(OwnConstants.StringLengthShort)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BOMDetail> BOMDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my code for **Project**

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    [Index("Project Code", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(OwnConstants.StringLengthShort)]
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    [Index("Description", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(OwnConstants.StringLengthShort)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BOM> BOMs { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to save a new entry to **BOM**. However, I'm getting null when I try to add **Project**. Below is my code to save.

```
    public override void Save()
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var currentID = (Entity as BOM).Id;
            var ExistingBOM = db.BOMs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.BOMCode == BOMCodeTextEdit.Text);
            if (ExistingBOM != null)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show("Record Exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                return;
            }

            if (currentID == 0)
            {                  
                BOM boms = new BOM()
                {
                    BOMRevision = BOMRevisionTextEdit.Text,
                    BOMCode = BOMCodeTextEdit.Text,
                    Title = TitleTextEdit.Text,
                };

                Project proj = new Project();
                int Project_Id = Convert.ToInt32(ProjectsLookUpEdit.EditValue);
                proj = db.Projects.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == Project_Id);
                db.Projects.Attach(proj);
                boms.Projects.Add(proj); // <== getting null here
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Save Successfully", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

Did I miss out anything?

**Updated Code**

```
int Project_Id = Convert.ToInt32(ProjectsLookUpEdit.EditValue);
var proj = db.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == Project_Id).ToList();
boms.Projects.Add(proj);
db.BOM.Add(boms);
```

Comment: Try `boms.Projects=proj;` instead `boms.Projects.Add(proj);`

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki I've tried it. I got an error `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ERP_System.Model.Project' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ERP_System.Model.Project>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
`

Comment: What if you delete `db.Projects.Attach(proj);`  and use only `Add()`

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki I got the same null exception error.

Comment: Ok,  You try add again exist `Project`, but you need add relationship to adding `Bom`. So get projects using `var projs =db.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == Project_Id).ToList();` and set it to `Bom`: `boms.Projects=projs`. If you want add again project and set i to `Bom` change `Id` after you use `SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki Thanks. I got it working. Check my updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying add single record where you need add `ICollection<T>`, change your query and take list instead single item.

```
var projs =db.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == Project_Id).ToList();
```